How to replace installed openssl and use my own openssl to build `make` script
I'm really new in Linuxverse, so please understand if I'm asking standard (or may a dumb) question.
I've seen so many post about how to remove openssl, but mostly they told to not remove it because it's may break some function. but I want to replace installed version of openssl and used my own openssl, because when I tried to run make script, the output tell me
[root@instance-20240412-073452 linux]# make v=r && cp *.out ../work
#echo ../.objs/centos_r64
make -f Makefile.obj
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ssh-key-2024-02-07/server/fd/LoginServer/linux'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `objs'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ssh-key-2024-02-07/server/fd/LoginServer/linux'
make _all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ssh-key-2024-02-07/server/fd/LoginServer/linux'
g++  -L../library/Lwp/lib_centos_r64 -L../library/Mysql-5.7.16/centos_x64/lib -L../library/openssl-1.1.1a/centos_x64/lib -L../library/openssl-1.1.1a/centos_x64/lib/engines-1.1 -L../library/openssl-1.1.1a/centos_x64/lib/pkgconfig -L../library/protobuf-master-3.0.0/centos_x64/lib -L../library/zlib-1.2.8/centos_x64/lib -Wl,-rpath,../library/Lwp/lib_centos_r64 -Wl,-rpath,../library/Mysql-5.7.16/centos_x64/lib -Wl,-rpath,../library/openssl-1.1.1a/centos_x64/lib -Wl,-rpath,../library/openssl-1.1.1a/centos_x64/lib/engines-1.1 -Wl,-rpath,../library/openssl-1.1.1a/centos_x64/lib/pkgconfig -Wl,-rpath,../library/protobuf-master-3.0.0/centos_x64/lib -Wl,-rpath,../library/zlib-1.2.8/centos_x64/lib  ../.objs/centos_r64/main/CenterServer.cpp.o ../.objs/centos_r64/main/login.pb.cc.o ../.objs/centos_r64/main/loginLog.cpp.o ../.objs/centos_r64/main/LoginServer.cpp.o ../.objs/centos_r64/main/main.cpp.o -Wl,-dn   -Wl,-dy -lprotobuf -lcurl -lssl -lmysqlclient -ldl -lpthread -lrt -lLwp_r64 -Wl,-dy -o LoginServer_r64.out 
/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /data/local/libs/curl-7.57.0/lib/libcurl.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1
/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.10, needed by /data/local/libs/curl-7.57.0/lib/libcurl.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/bin/ld: ../.objs/centos_r64/main/LoginServer.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'HMAC@@OPENSSL_1_1_0'
../library/openssl-1.1.1a/centos_x64/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [LoginServer_r64.out] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ssh-key-2024-02-07/server/fd/LoginServer/linux'
make: *** [all] Error 2

specific warning that I concern is this caused make failed to compile:

/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.10, needed by /data/local/libs/curl-7.57.0/lib/libcurl.so, may conflict with libssl.so.1.1

when I tried to check the version of openssl using openssl version it show OpenSSL 1.1.0c  10 Nov 2016 which is what I want, but as far as I know, there should not have libssl.so.10. Or maybe I mess up the openssl, so there's 2 openssl installed in my centos?
So there's some way to disable libssl.so.10 from running while compiling make? I've tried to rename libssl.so.10 to libssl.so.10.bak but make still showing above error.

It looks like the issue is that curl-7.57.0/lib/libcurl.so is built against the older libssl/libcrypto. But why are you even trying to build software that depends on these old (possibly compromised) libraries?

@steeldriver I just downloaded a ready-to-build game source code and intent to build a webserver that are included to my centos. does curl-7.57.0 is not sync with openssl-1.1.0c?

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Centos ecosystem - however you can look at the output of ldd /data/local/libs/curl-7.57.0/lib/libcurl.so to see how it resolves library dependencies
